# Files: Filestream and StreamWriter Wrapper Class

Tags: c#

I have a confusion here in understanding the relationship between object fs and 
object sw in the following line of code.

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

The confusion is  in understanding whether,

1>  Is sw just pointing to the object fs
2>  when fs is passed as parameter to StreamWriter constructor which members are initialized to the contents of object fs.

Please explain the mechanism in detail how FileStream class and StreamWriter class are accomplishing the task through object references fs and sw.

```
     using System;

     using System.IO;

     class File_Write
        {
           public void Write_Data()
            {

                int empid = 12;
                string empname = "sean";



            FileStream fs = new FileStream("E:\\Files_Demo\\File_Write.txt", FileMode.Create,
                FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Good Morning");
                sw.WriteLine("Provide_EmployeeDetails");

                sw.WriteLine("Employee Id={0}", empid);


                Console.WriteLine("Written to file...Success");
                Console.Read();


            }
      }
```

Comment: related So question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144794/what-does-stream-means-what-are-its-characteristics

Comment: msdn explanation of files and streams: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

A `Stream` is just a sequence of bytes that you can read, write, and/or seek (depending on the type of stream). It's just raw binary data, with no knowledge of what the data means and how to process it.

A `StreamWriter` is used to write *text* on a stream, using the specified text encoding (UTF-8 by default). Writing text directly on a `Stream` without using a `StreamWriter` is possible, but not very convenient (you would need to manually convert the string to bytes)

Similarly, a `StreamReader` is used to read text from a `Stream`.

> 1> Is sw just pointing to the object fs

It holds a reference to it, yes.

> 2> when fs is passed as parameter to StreamWriter constructor which members are initialized to the contents of object fs.

`fs` doesn't have a content; it's just a way to access the underlying data (in this case, a file on disk). So `StreamWriter` isn't "initialized to the content of object fs"; it just stores a reference to `fs` so that it can manipulate it later.

Comment: I know that, however why fs is pased as parameter to streamwriter constructor.

Comment: I'm going to guess that if the OP doesn't have a grasp on files and streams they probably will also struggle with text encoding.

Comment: @Gt_R, since a `StreamWriter` writes on a `Stream`, you need to give it a `Stream` when you create it. Passing `fs` to the `StreamWriter` constructor means that the writer will write on `fs`.

Comment: @Gt_R: you pass the `FileStream` as a parameter to the `StreamWriter` ctor because if you didn't how would the `StreamWriter` know you wanted to operate on the `FileStream`?  Remember, not all files are text files, so you may choose some other mechanism besides `StreamWriter` to operate on the `FileStream` depending on the data.

Comment: @Gt_R, I completed my answer

Comment: @ Thomas Levesque:  Perfect!!   :)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Good Point.  very helpful.